# How to utilize prepocessor variables when using Intel Visual Fortran

Tags: windows, preprocessor, fortran

I would like to compile a Fortran 90 (fixed format) library under Windows. However, I cannot understand the error of prepocessor variables.

```
    Say the sample file is VF_TestPreprocessor.F: 

    program VF_TestPreprocessor

    implicit Integer(A-Z)

    Parameter (TestAlpha=22,TestBeta=TestGamma)

    print *, TestBeta

    end program VF_TestPreprocessor
```

Under Linux, I can use `ifort VF_TestPreprocessor.F -DTestGamma=25` to compile, and run.

However, under windows, I cannot use `ifort VF_TestPreprocessor.F /DTestGamma=25` to compile. The error message is `error #6592: This symbol must be a defined parameter, an enumerator, or an argument of an inquiry function that evaluates to a compile-time constant.   [TestGamma]`. Could you help to analyse the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `ifort` doesn't run the preprocessor. I have no experience with `ifort`, but [this page](http://nf.nci.org.au/facilities/software/FORTRAN/Intel10/doc/main_for/mergedProjects/bldaps_for/common/bldaps_use_fpp.htm) (the first hit in Google on `ifort preprocessor`) says that on Windows the preprocessor is only run on files ending in an extension of `.fpp`.

So, I guess there are (at least) two solutions:

- Rename your files to end in `.fpp`;
- invoke ifort with the `/fpp` switch.

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestions! However, neither of the two solutions works. The error messsage of running "./ifort.exe VF_TestPreprocessor.F /DDEFMAXXCNAME=25 /fpp" is instead "link: unknown option -- s", which suggests the compilation part succeeds. (Another clue is "./ifort.exe VF_TestPreprocessor.F /DDEFMAXXCNAME=25 /fpp /c" succeeds.) Could you help to comment about the new error message?

Comment: The error messsage of "link: unknown option -- s", is actually my another mistake. http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=81388&o=d&s=lr